# Using Jython and Tomcat in bundle - should we even try to?

Tags: java, python, tomcat

Have you ever used Jython in bundle with tomcat in any serious, production-ready service?

What pros and cons can you name?
Is it worth trying if all guys in team has no problems with coding on Java, but know python as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with Jython is that it lags behind the latest versions of Python. It's currently at version 2.5, and a lot of good stuff has come in 2.6 and 2.7. I don't know when Jython will get to Python 3.

My recommendation would be to either go all Python, perhaps with Django, or if you want to stay in the Java world, consider Groovy/Grails. Both of these are well-beaten paths, with significant communities to help you when things go wrong.

Comment: (gotta say Python put some *major effort* into *shaking off the pursuers*)

Comment: Well, it's true that Python has changed a lot since 2.0, but I don't know that it's changes have been more rapid than Ruby. But the Ruby folks I know speak positively about JRuby, where no-one I've encountered in the Python community talks about Jython. I've heard more about IronPython, and even PyPy.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly viable yes, plenty of financials do it (and gain the power of the JVM and all of those lovely Java class libs and other Java based APIs).  As @Eric Wilson mentioned, it does lag behind.

It shouldn't take you too long to prototype this - try giving it a go and see!

Answer (score 1):

You can also look into scala if you decide to remain close to java world and looking for something different. Its compatible with java. I have found it a very good language to work with. It also has  web framework called liftweb.

Comment: Scala is another good option, particularly if you want the static typing benefits of Java.